# Out of memory on collectionFactory->create()

Tags: magento2, module, collection, memory-leak

I'm getting a strange error on code which previously worked and now dont.

```
    <?php


    namespace Itstod\LinkedProducts\Model;

    use Itstod\LinkedProducts\Api\LinkInterface;
    use Itstod\LinkedProducts\Model\ResourceModel\LinkedProducts\Collection;
    use Itstod\LinkedProducts\Model\ResourceModel\LinkedProducts\CollectionFactory;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

    class Resthandler implements LinkInterface
    {
    /**
     * @var Product
     */
     protected $product;

    /**
     * @var LinkedProduct[]
     */
    private $instances = [];

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @api
     * @param string $sku product sku.
     * @return LinkedProduct[].
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function get($sku) {

         /**
         * @var LinkedProduct[]
         */
        $returnvalue = [];

        $this->product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);

        $id = $this->product->getId();

        /** @var Collection $collection**/
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('head_product_id', $id);

        // $collection = $collection->getSelect();


        /** @var \Itstod\LinkedProducts\Model\LinkedProduct $prod */
        /*
        foreach ($collection as $prod)
        {

            $returnvalue[] = $this->productRepository->getById($prod->getData('linked_product_id'));

        }
        */

        return $returnvalue;
    }
}
```

this code is giving me:

```
    "Fatal Error: 'Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 803225600 bytes)' in '\/home\/<url>\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-eav\/Model\/Entity\/Collection\/AbstractCollection.php' on line 249"
```

and as you can i see i commented out most of the code to find this error.
The crash is happening in the ->create() function as i have tried it on its own and its still crashing.

**Update!**

Found the error, i was trying to extend the wrong abstract collection, in my collection class.

Comment: I can see the blank line before the declaration of name space.  This may be typo mistakes..

Comment: shouldnt be the namespace, the function runs fine without the collectionfactory and returns an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

its look like a there is no error in code check once your memory limit and increase it after that still show the same error then you can look into code error .

Comment: I have increased the memory limit once from 756M to 1024M with no other changes and i still got the error, is this what you mean by memory limit increase?

Comment: still your facing the same error ?

Comment: after increasing from 756 to 1024 i still have the same error yes

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to fetch a large amount of data from your Collection

```
 Itstod\LinkedProducts\Model\ResourceModel\LinkedProducts\CollectionFactory
```

You should be memmory_limit min 2GB as per as Magento doc 2GB https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_php-set.html

Else, you have to add limit or pager on your collection

Check https://www.fmeextensions.com/blog/how-to-add-magnto-2-pagination-to-custom-collection/

Comment: Are you sure? because its only two rows with 4 columns in the database, that shouldnt crash it right?

Comment: And it gets stuck before i even try to use any data as it crashes on ->create()